# Requested JSON parse failed while getGetFeatureInfoUrl

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, json, getfeatureinfo

I am trying to get the feature attributes from WMS service published in GeoServer and showing the attributes as a popup in the .NET application.

When I make an Ajax call it gives "requested JSON parse failed" exception, However, the URL works and returns JSON data in a browser.

PFB code block:

```
 var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
        { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'jsonp' }); //text/html

      if (url) {
          var parser = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
          var lookup = {};
          $.ajax({
              url: url,
              dataType: 'jsonp',
              method: 'GET',
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              success: function (response) {
                              alert("hI");                                  
                          },
              error:  function(jqXHR, exception) {
                          if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                              alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                          } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                              alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                          } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                              alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                          } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                              alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                          } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                              alert('Time out error.');
                          } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                              alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                          } else {
                              alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                          }
                      }
          });

      }
```

The JSON response on browser from the URL is:

`{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"village_maps.115","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[79.13895583,25.3233091],[79.13482866,25.32499247],[79.13317419,25.32360682],[79.12904055,25.32355175],[79.11112382,25.32624913],[79.11054308,25.32213731],[79.10696928,25.32399947],[79.1034709,25.32324635],[79.09974985,25.31942675],[79.09800786,25.32022119],[79.0979736,25.31867895],[79.09166887,25.31635774],[79.08927284,25.31821429],[79.08661964,25.31754376],[79.07432635,25.32064035],[79.07417549,25.32250699],[79.07728205,25.32362325],[79.08025674,25.32743095],[79.08831236,25.32775063],[79.09032527,25.33283685],[79.08757208,25.33551219],[79.07363746,25.34013379],[79.07406066,25.34194949],[79.07257536,25.34266333],[79.07427301,25.34407714],[79.07571542,25.35252829],[79.08648018,25.35161346],[79.09057063,25.35709824],[79.09046858,25.35497181],[79.08648332,25.34991794],[79.09656147,25.34616603],[79.09976983,25.35526709],[79.10152538,25.3574017],[79.10472238,25.35755957],[79.10617664,25.36085029],[79.11197018,25.35874088],[79.11217002,25.35463277],[79.11563481,25.35019114],[79.11465262,25.348675],[79.11888327,25.34534672],[79.12336584,25.34908317],[79.12612299,25.34570295],[79.13045243,25.34409387],[79.13712699,25.34887448],[79.13983827,25.34651654],[79.13916554,25.34453145],[79.14239623,25.34280575],[79.14273195,25.33875767],[79.1448726,25.33784395],[79.14887941,25.33979993],[79.1535527,25.33947772],[79.15312606,25.33435852],[79.15454125,25.33390489],[79.15492136,25.330539],[79.15069001,25.3216973],[79.14512387,25.32357109],[79.13895583,25.3233091]]]]},"geometry_name":"geom","properties":{"objectid_1":115,"objectid_2":115,"objectid":115,"shape_leng":0.313447905145,"pipeline_l":2.72376,"shape_le_1":0.313447907911,"shape_area":0.00194710986264}}],"totalFeatures":"unknown","numberReturned":1,"timeStamp":"2019-08-21T05:33:08.387Z","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"}}}`

Comment: At least the coordinates obviously are not in EPSG:3857 but in EPSG:4326.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have changed the Coordinate reference system in my code and in GeoServer Layer as well, But still the error is same :- "Requested JSON parse failed".

Comment: This time error same same "Requested JSON parse failed" , However when I run the url created in browser it gave below response :<ServiceException code="InvalidFormat" locator="info_format">
Invalid format 'jsonp', supported formats are [text/plain, application/vnd.ogc.gml, text/xml, application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1, text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1, text/html, application/json]
</ServiceException>

Comment: On using "Application/JSON" , Url response on browser is : {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[],"totalFeatures":"unknown","numberReturned":0,"timeStamp":"2019-08-21T07:23:42.893Z","crs":null}

Comment: I guess that the parsing error is another issue but crs was certainly wrong.

Comment: Yes , Thats right. After changing crs in GeoServer the WMS layer superimposed on OSM base layer properly , But response of url from getGetFeatureInfoUrl function is blank.. Any idea what may be the issue , I am new to Geoserver and OpenLayers .. Shall I make any change in GeoServer configuration ? Please suggest.

Comment: One more thing , How did you judge that the CRS was wrong from the JSON response earlier.

Comment: My view is :   var view = new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 4
      }) .. url is prepared from :  var viewResolution = (view.getResolution());
          var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:4326',
            { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html' }); // text/html or JSON

Comment: Does the server support jsonp?  Try replacing `dataType: 'jsonp',` with `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: By changing dataType: 'json' the generated url from getGetFeatureInfoUrl returns valid json from server , but in console I see CORS policy error. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Is there a way that we can enable CORS policy in GeoServer

Comment: Maybe answers to this question on using `$.ajax` with `jasonp` can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943630/basic-example-of-using-ajax-with-jsonp. `jsonp` is intended just for evoiding CORS problems.

Comment: `One more thing , How did you judge that the CRS was wrong from the JSON ` because the response  `[79.13712699,25.34887448]` appears to be in decimal degrees, unless you've requested a very small area, but [epsg:3857](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857) uses metres as unit of measure.  If you have a pure GeoJSON response then you have decimal degrees long /lat and not EPSG:4326 which uses lat/long order...

Comment: GeoServer documentation describes how to enable CORS https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html  jsonp is an older method of bypassing CORS but requires the server to process a callback parameter (which isn't supported by default and also requires jsonpCallback: 'parseResponse', in the ajax options) https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html

Comment: @nmtoken OpenLayers uses the view coordinates, resolution and projection to construct a request in whatever projection was used to construct the layer (which might be client reprojected) so changing the projection would not change the data layout, but a mismatch of coordinates and projection would likely result in an "off the world" request which returns no data.

Comment: Thanks ! I was able to enable CORS by un-commenting the filter in web.xml. This fixed the CORS error and I was able to parse the response JOSN and my WMS Layer was superimposed on OSM.

Comment: I wished to use google image as base layer rather the OSM layer from openlayers. Is it possible to use google Imagery as a base map in openlayers ?

Comment: Google doesn't allow its tiles to be used except in a Google map, so you would need to superimpose maps and keep them synchronised, which in most cases isn't practical.  If you mean Google's satellite imagery there are alternatives available (some even use the same data as Google).  Many are free but require an API key and have monthly usage limits but `https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}` is currently unrestricted.